# CSS 3d animation transform size in loop

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div exact same like http://red-button.webflow.io/
but not getting the exact results

My code is below

```css
@keyframes scale-div {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }  
}
@keyframes scale-border {
  0% {
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
  }  
}



.scale {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

  animation: scale-border 2s steps(300, end) infinite;
 content: '';
   border-radius: 5px;
    background: #d70b0b;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    line-height: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;

line-height: -moz-block-height;
}
```

```html
 <div class="scale">Get A Free Estimate</div>
```

I achieved 70% of results but not 100%

Need exact same animation and text and box size transformation as per example link

Comment: it's a simple scale animation

Comment: Can you please make it exact same like example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use scale animation like below:

```css
@keyframes scale-div {
  to {
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(1.05,1.05,1);
  }
}

.scale {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  animation: scale-div 0.5s infinite linear alternate;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d70b0b;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="scale">Get A Free Estimate</div>
```

To avoid the bad effect for text you can consider translateZ and perspective:

```css
@keyframes scale-div {
  to {
    transform:perspective(100px) translate(-50%, -50%) translateZ(5px);
  }
}

.scale {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:perspective(100px) translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  animation: scale-div 0.5s infinite linear alternate;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d70b0b;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="scale">Get A Free Estimate</div>
```